# Chef: extending yum_package provider to check for version number in environment file

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have 3 chef environments (dev, qa, prod) that all share one cookbook.  The environment files contain RPM version numbers:

```
{
  "name": "dev",
  ...
  "rpms": {
    "blah": "1.0",
    "blah2": "2.0"
  }
  ...
}
```

which the recipe uses:

```
rpms = node['rpms']
env = node['name']

yum_package "blah" do
    version "#{rpms['blah']}-#{env}"
end

yum_package "blah2" do
    version "#{rpms['blah2']}-common"
end
```

The issue arises when I want to add a new RPM.  I want to install it **only** in dev for testing, so I add the appropriate `yum_package` call to the recipe and add the version number to the dev.json environment file.  However, deployments to qa and prod will fail because the RPM version number is missing from the qa and prod environment files.

Is there a way to extend the `yum_package` provider to check if the version number is specified in the environment file (and skip if no version is specified)?  Or is there a more elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: I think more elegant would be that you iterate over the key and value using `each` method.

    rpms.each {
      |k,v|
       version "#{v}"
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the comment of [doptimusprime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1629262/doptimusprime), the following should work (with the option to not specify the exact version and use the latest instead):

```
{
  "name": "dev",
  ...
  "rpms": {
    "blah": "1.0",
    "blah2": "2.0",
    "latestblah": nil
  }
  ...
}
```

```rb
node['rpms'].each do |p,v|
  yum_package p do
    version v if v
  end
end
```

(`version` is optional and will be only called, if a version is specified)

Comment: Building on this idea, if some rpms have version-release values (like 1.0-dev or 2.0-common", I would simply update the environment files to include the release values, like `"blah": "1.0-dev",`, right?

Comment: You can put any version number there that is accepted by the underlying provider (yum in this case).